# How can I get openSSL to run on my web server with a PHP5-FPM chroot?

Tags: email, php-fpm, php5, openssl, chroot

On my web server, I changed the chroot to only have access to the root of my website's home directory as opposed to the rest of the file system, for security purposes. However, I've noticed that since the change I can't seem to get OpenSSL to be recognized within PHP. Trying to send mail from my server, I get the following error:

```
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: Success in /public/lib/mailer/class.smtp.php on line 274 2014-05-04 23:32:29   CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2014-05-04 23:32:29  SERVER -> CLIENT:  2014-05-04 23:32:29 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:  SMTP connect() failed
```

What OpenSSL files do I need to include in the chroot in order to make the script run? Is there any other way I can have PHP access OpenSSL without changing my chroot? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i bind-mounted /etc/ssl, /etc/pki/ca-trust, /etc/pki/tls, into [CHROOT] folder and it worked (for CentOS 7, Rocky 8).
e.g.:
mkdir -p [CHROOT]/etc/pki/tls
mount --bind -o ro  /etc/pki/tls  [CHROOT]/etc/pki/tls